# How to show a file browser and Select files from Liferay Document Library in my custom portlet using ItemSelector

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-aui, primereact

I want to display a file browser to show the Liferay Document Library files and folders and let the user select or upload his files, in my custom portlet.

There is such implementation in the Liferay portal itself now, but I could not find its source code in the Liferay portal source code. (see attached photo)

I need to have both the frontend and backend implementation of **ItemSelector** for such a use case. I searched Liferay documents but did not find any examples.

I use Liferay 7.3, React and PrimeReact components in the front-end and REST Services in the back-end and have not used JSP in the back-end. (should I use JSP to open the selection modal in the front-end?)

[image: The needed file browser shot]

Comment: ItemSelector standard component is made of jsp mvc with some core js included. Using react codebase it's hard to mix things, I guess.

Comment: @DanieleBaggio I can include JSP in my code.  Then what should I do?